# Get highest number from table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the highest number (122,28.22) from the table cells with specific class.

This is my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">3.2091</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">122,28.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">4.8271</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is really what I've tried, but it just returns NaN. So math.max doesn't work on it.

```
var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.id').map(function(){
         return $(this).text()
}))

alert(high);
```

Comment: `$(this).text()` is a string - convert it to a number.

Comment: Those are not numbers. You need to remove extra formatting first, and convert them to number inside Map.

Comment: Try to return with parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `NaN` as your number `122,28.22` contains a `,` so you can change it to a valid number  format using `replace`

```js
function findMax(){
  let td = document.getElementsByClassName('id')
  let value = [...td].map(e=> +e.innerText.replace(/,/,''))
  console.log(Math.max(...value))
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">3.2091</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">122,28.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">4.8271</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onClick="findMax()">Find max </button>
```

Comment: @alex always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `return Number($(this).text().replace(',',''))`
Text, even less formatted text is not handled as number by Math methods.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `$(this).text()` to a number:

```js
var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.id').map(function() {
  return parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/\,/g, ""));
}));

console.log(high);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">3.2091</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">122,28.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">4.8271</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above will de-format the text unfortunately, because it's not handled as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that add an id to the table and use `documentquerySelectorAll`. Use spread operator to use the array `map` method which an innerText to get the content of the `td`. Before returning from the `map`, check for `,` and replace that, & use array `sort` method to find the maximum value

```js
let k = [...document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll('tr')].map((item) => {
  let val = item.querySelector('td').innerText;
  if (val.includes(',')) {
    return val.replace(',', '')
  }
  return val
}).sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]

console.log(k)
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">3.2091</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">122,28.22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">4.8271</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Brk .. This works Great .. And Also Can You tell me How Can i get lowest Value from td ??

Comment: @alex Instead of `b - a` do `a-b` inside the sort function

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.id').map(function(){
     return $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '');
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() { var listArray=[] $('.id').each(function(){ listArray.push(parseInt($(this).text())) }); console.log(Math.max(...listArray))

Answer (score 0):

> 122,28.22

Avoid comma separated in between the values